# OracleJet CSS automatically insert new div into Button tag

Tags: css, sass, oracle-jet

I was using oraclejet and set a simple split button. The resulted DOM is filled with 2 more span tags that generated automatically. How can I disable such behavior?

The split menu button is from the tutorial link
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/uiComponents-menuButton-menuButtonComponent.html

Answer (score 1):

Would be great if you could share the generated code. Anyway, JET is creating "a lot" of DOM elements on its own - due to styling, accessibility etc. I think there is not much that you could do to prevent it from happening.